# Is there way to position border with css (IMAGE EXAMPLE)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, border

Below are a couple of examples of what I want:

**Example 1:**

[image: example 1]

**Example 2:**

[image]

I tried by using `background` but I don't know how to make the background smaller than its container, so I decided to try with `border-bottom` and to position it with `sth` like `10px-top`.

I've tried:

```css
background: rgba(196,196,196,0.8);
background-position: -10px 10px;
```

However, I cant find how to postion border... Is there some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with `:before`

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <br />
  <p class="text alt">Amet cum et ad earum commodi</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  padding: 50px;
  background: url(https://placedog.net/1000/500?id=12);
  background-size: cover;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Change the values `top, bottom, left, right` in the `:before` to suit your needs.

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/74kLwyxb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `border-image` css property. More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/)

**DEMO**

```css
#borderimg1 {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
  -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
  border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
}

#borderimg2 {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch;
  -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch;
  border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 stretch;
}
```

```html
<p id="borderimg1">Here, the image tiles to fill the area. The image is rescaled if necessary, to avoid dividing tiles.</p>
<p id="borderimg2">Here, the image is stretched to fill the area.</p>
```

Comment: I have some text and I want background on that text but smaller and wider than the text... you can see what I want here:  https://prnt.sc/omczt1